# How to recieve image in nodejs and store it in database sent through react dropzone

Tags: node.js, reactjs

This is the dropzone to upload the file on client side

```
<Dropzone
            onDrop={this.onDrop}
            multiple={false}
            className="dropzone"
    >
    <div><img src={this.state.image.preview} width={200} height={200} alt=""/></div>
    </Dropzone>
```

Now i want to send it to server using axios .
For that i have used form data to send the image .
Now how do i receive the file and store it in the database .

This is the image object that i have in the client side

```
lastModified :1491372516733  
lastModifiedDate:Wed Apr 05 2017 11:38:36 GMT+0530 (IST)  
name:"section.png"  
preview:"blob:http://localhost:8080/4a8006c7-1b6d-4ed6-b277-35c63f898ef7"  
size:99814  
type:"image/png"  
webkitRelativePath:""  
__proto__:File
```

Comment: Does it answer your question? It showcases a simple php server implementation https://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax  Once you can upload the file to server, you can insert into database.

Comment: i need to know how to do it in nodejs